# How do I make pressing the Enter key cause focus to move to the cell below like Excel's default behavior?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid, onkeypress

I am using an Infragistics UltraWinGrid v9.1.
I want to allow the user to enter numerical data in a cell, press **Enter** and then have the focus on the cell below, like you see in Excel. It appears that the KeyUp event might be better than the KeyPressed event for this, but I keep throwing an exception that I have gone beyond the bounds of the UltraWinGrid even though I start at the top of a full grid. Here is the code I've tried:

```
    private void ugrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        UltraGrid grid = (UltraGrid)sender;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Go down one row
            UltraGridCell cell = grid.ActiveCell;
            int currentRow = grid.ActiveRow.Index;
            int col = cell.Column.Index;
            grid.Rows[currentRow + 1].Cells[grid.ActiveCell].Activate();
        }
    }
```

I expected this to make the cell in the same column but one row below to become the active cell with the call, 
grid.Rows[currentRow + 1].Cells[grid.ActiveCell].Activate();

Instead an exception is thrown:

> An exception of type
>   'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in
>   Infragistics2.Shared.v9.1.dll but was
>   not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Index was outside the
>   bounds of the array.

Since I'm on row 0 and there exists a row 1 this is a surprise to me. The values for currentRow and col are 0 and 28 respectively. What would be a better approach?
btw I can do this again the cell below, where the values are currentRow = 1 and col = 28. The same exception is thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone answered my question on the Infragistics fora...

```
    private void ugrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (UltraGrid)sender;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Go down one row
            grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.BelowCell);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if what I'm saying is valid also for the v9.1 but you can also do something like this:

```
yourGrid.KeyActionMappings.Add(new GridKeyActionMapping(Keys.Enter, UltraGridAction.BelowCell, 0, UltraGridState.Row, SpecialKeys.All, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void ulGrvProducts_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            UltraGrid grid =  (UltraGrid)sender;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                 //Go down one row
                grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.BelowCell);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After using `grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.BelowCell)` , active row will change but next cell is not be in edit mode.

Comment: If you use this "grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.EnterEditMode);" after the PerformAction the cell will be in edit mode.